# Facing problem with popoverControllerShouldDismissPopover delegate

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad, uipopovercontroller

i used this delegate to avoid dismissing of my UIPopover controller from my View.

```
-(BOOL)popoverControllerShouldDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController
{
    return NO;
}
```

there is a problem i am facing with these delegate .

i cant able to do any actions or any process in my View after i implemented this delegate.

so i am troubling with this problem .how can i avoid this problem with displaying my UIpopover.can any one tell me please.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you assigned your view to the `passThroughViews` property? It's in the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPopoverController_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009306)